# can't properly dynamically load and set up game state

Tags: java, swing

all right, this is a complicated question, so let's try to start this up
so, i'm sure many of you have played a game, where they show buttons with some identification of a save file, and when you press it, it will retrieve the save state from that file and start playing
I want to implement something similar for a simple rpg(think simplified fire emblem, if you're played it).
so what I do is set a jpanel with buttons with the actioncommand "load and play save file", and this is the code I try to use in an actionlistener to execute that functionality
rpggame is a jpanel with my relevant characters, a cursor, etc, and setgame is a method that helps set it up
(using the button text is to try to retrieve a particular file)
using the +".dat" is to try to get the serialized state

```
else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("load and play saved file")) {
    JButton source = (JButton)(e.getSource());
    try {
        newgame = loadChapterState(source.getText() + ".dat");
        newgame.SetUpGame();
        //newgame.setCursor(newgame.cursor);
        CardLayout layout = (CardLayout)(overallgame.getLayout());
        layout.show(overallgame, GAME);
        //requestFocusInWindow
        newgame.requestFocus /*InWindow*/ (true);

        dummyframe.repaint();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dummyframe, "Darn it!", "Error in retrieval", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        //ex.printStackTrace();
    }​
```

this is the code for the loadChapterState(game-state loading) method

```
​       public static RPGGame loadChapterState(String file) throws IOException {
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        RPGGame gamedata = null;
        try {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            gamedata = (RPGGame) ois.readObject();
            gamedata.setCursor(gamedata.cursor);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, there was an error reaching the file");
            System.out.println("You will not be able to play with this state");
            //ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            ois.close();
            return gamedata;
        }
    }
```

what confuses me is that when I run this, I get the image of the game map perfectly, but I can't actually move the cursor with input to a keylistener, despite resetting it in the loading method above with the setCursor method(I had trouble with that earlier when just getting any old copy of that game map).

now, I do have the save state loaded later in my main method here like this.

```
System.out.println("Would you like to create a file?");
 try {
     newgame = loadChapterState("stuff.dat");
     newgame.SetUpGame();
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }

 //finally constructs master panel that can flip between main menu and running game
 overallgame = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
 overallgame.add(mainmenupanel, MAIN_MENU);
 overallgame.add(newgame, GAME);
 overallgame.add(creditpanel, CREDITS);
 overallgame.add(chapterstartmenupanel, CHAPTERSTART);
 overallgame.add(showsavefilespanel, SAVE_FILES);​
```

(this one can work with the cursor perfectly, with the combination of another part of my actionlistener and this next bit after assigning this listener to a JButton with the "start" actioncommmand)

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("start")) {
    //dummyframe.add(newgame);
    //mainmenupanel=null;
    CardLayout layout = (CardLayout)(overallgame.getLayout()); //retrieves the overall layout
    layout.show(overallgame, GAME); //uses it to switch to main game panel
    newgame.requestFocus(true); //need to redirect focus to the game rather than original main menu
    dummyframe.repaint();
}​
```

if requested, i'll show the rpggame class.
I guess what I want is, how can I get my cursor working properly from the "load and play save fie" command?
thanks for the help!

Comment: *"what confuses me is that when I run this, I get the image of the game map perfectly, but I can't actually move the cursor with input to a keylistener, despite resetting it in the loading method above with the setCursor method(I had trouble with that earlier when just getting any old copy of that game map)."* - If, you're saving the physical component of the game, then the listeners are not serialised as well, they will need to be initialised.

Comment: Object serialisation is generally a poor choice of the long term storage of objects and you should avoid serializing ANY UI based component, there a bunch of issues, the listeners are just one.  Instead, consider using something like [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) to save the "state" data you need, which should be independent of the "view"/"presentation"/UI

Comment: *"all right, this is a complicated question.."* Given that load of words contains only one `?` and it is embedded in a code snippet, I figure you forgot to ask a question.  Please form and ask a specific question, if the question is hidden among the words above, add a `?` to it.

Comment: MadProgrammer, I know that listeners can't be serialized, so my setCursor does manually reregister so I can have it back after deserializing... nd as I mentioned, if I opened the game state a slightly different way, it works. so I don't believe serialization has a hand in this, certainly not in the way of losing the listener completely. maybe the problem is somewhere else, or relates to another aspect of serialization?

Comment: I believe your question is 'how do I set the cursor for a deserialized Swing component?' Is that correct? If so I suggest changing the title to 'Setting the cursor for a deserialized Swing component'.

Comment: it seems like dynamically loading the desired state in only one place, right when the button to start is clicked, is working the way I want to. maybe creating multiple states, one in main method and other dynamically, created some issue I didn't understand